# UnBuffered Channel not working in synchronous way

Tags: go, channel

I am quite new to GoLang world and was trying goroutines/channels.
As far as I understand, channels are bidirectional way of communication among goroutines.
If we create a channel with length 0, it is supposed to be a synchronous channel and it signifies that unless some goroutine (i.e. consumer) reads the values from channel, the producer won't be able to move forward.

I tried below example to test this but I am not getting expected results.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var done = make(chan bool)
var msgs = make(chan int)

func produce() {
    for i := 0; i < 40; i++ {
        //fmt.Println("sending")
        fmt.Println("Produced: ", i)
        msgs <- i
        //fmt.Println("Channel size is: ", len(msgs))
    }
    fmt.Println("Before closing channel")
    close(msgs)
    fmt.Println("Before passing true to done")
    

}

func consume() {
    for msg := range msgs {
        //fmt.Println("Going to take one, Channel size is: ", len(msgs))
        fmt.Println("Consumer: ", msg)
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)

    }
    done <- true
    
}

func main() {
    go produce()
    go consume()
    <-done
    fmt.Println("After calling DONE")
}
```

Output:

```
Produced:  0
Produced:  1
Consumer:  0
Consumer:  1
Produced:  2
Consumer:  2
...
```

I was expecting output to be

```
Produced:  0
Consumer:  0
Produced:  1
Consumer:  1
Produced:  2
Consumer:  2
```

Please help me out here with pointing what I am doing wrong?

Comment: One thing what might be happening here is that the delay between the loop start moment and execution of print statement in consumer is causing above behavior. 
What I mean by that is after putting the value in channel ( msgs <- i executed), consumer start execution but just before it's print statement is executed (fmt.Println("Consumer: ", msg) is executed), producer produces and pushes new value in channel, and we get two consecutive producers. 
Is this the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (unbuffered) channel reads/writes will occur in the sequence you expect: one write; one read; one write; one read etc.

The `fmt.Println` calls in the producer/consumer goroutines, however, are *not* synchronized - and as such the producer may get its `fmt.Println` function in to the scheduler before the `consumer`.

And since the `consumer` sleeps - it voluntarily gives a cue to the scheduler to let other goroutines run ahead of it. So the `producer` will most likely always get its second `fmt.Println` run before `consumer` awakes.

You can see your expected behavior in action in the playground if you move the sleep to the `producer` goroutine: https://play.golang.org/p/5x9_yyUaMiJ - however you should not rely on these timing tricks. If you want to ensure a function's execution sequence relative to another goroutine, those tasks must be synchronized as well. With channel reads/writes - only the reads/writes are guaranteed to be goroutine safe & in sequence.